# SSRS - Using the LEFT() function on a multi-valued parameter?

Tags: t-sql, parameters, ssrs-2008

I'm having some issues trying to use the LEFT() function with a multi-valued parameter that allows users to select all values. In my dataset, I use the following code:

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE AccountValue BETWEEN 10000 and 50000
 AND CodeValue IN ('',100,LEFT(@Parameter,3))
```

Basically, the results that should be pulled in the matrix are all accounts between 10000 and 50000, that have a code value of blank, 100, or the left 3 characters of the values the user selects in the parameter.  The values in the parameter are as follows: '200 - Finance', '300 - Admin', '400 - HR', etc.  Code column values in the table are 100, 200, 300, 400, etc. So I use the LEFT function to split the string values of the parameter. This works fine if the user only selects one parameter. But when they select more than one or all, then it messes up the syntax of the query, returning the error "The left function requires 2 argument(s)." Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you use the value as the number only and set labels for each value instead?

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Sorry for the novice question, that fixed it!

Comment: No problem. I find there's a lot of documentation missing for SSRS and these things are just hard to figure out sometimes. Feel free to write yourself a nice answer below, so other people coming here can see exactly how you solved it. Then accept your own answer when you can. It's the SO way. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone, managed to get around this by specifying a label and a value for the parameter in the parameter properties.  The label, being what the user sees, as "Finance," "Admin," etc. Their values being the code values 001/002/etc.  Then the clause for the dataset set to

```
WHERE CodeValue IN ('',100,@Parameter)
```